# Find Apache Directory

Tags: ruby, apache, bash

I'm looking for a way to programatically detect the location of the Apache config directory, and the name of the configuration file. Bonus points if this is in Ruby or Bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Location and name of the config file is determined during compilation, so if you look at compilation settings you will be able to determine it

```
apachectl -V
```

will show you a line like this

```
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

so in ruby you can extract it with something like this:

```
IO.popen('apachectl -V').read.match(/SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="(.*)"/)[1]
```

Comment: You could do that either in Ruby or Bash.  You better get your bonus points. :)